# How to python script in php web server

Tags: php, python, web

I am trying execute python script from php, on my local server it works fine.
But after hosting on web i am getting error like this:

```
"Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in/home/a1608290/public_html/searc2.php on line 58"
```

Is there a way to execute python script in php web server???

link to my website:http://wikiquery.comuf.com/index.php

in php  this how i am running my python script:

```
$tmp =`/usr/bin/python2.7 wiki.py .$var`;
```

or

```
$tmp = exec("python wiki.py .$var");
```

for both ways i am getting the similar error

Thankz in advance

Comment: I don't think 000webhost will allow you to run python scripts on their servers. Their free hosting does not include executing python scripts. If you want to do this you will have to buy a hosting service that allows this.

Answer (score 3):

### Reason

Your PHP configuration doesn't allow the `shell_exec()` function. This is one of the functions disabled when PHP is run in Safe Mode.

### Solution

Generally speaking, I discourage you to disable safe mode for a production environment. You can use `ini_set` to enable `shell_exec` in current session, so that you will not expose your server in a danger position.

```
<?php

  $old_settings = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
  $new_settings = implode(',', array_diff($old_settings, ['shell_exec']));
  ini_set('disable_functions', $new_settings);

?>
```

Here is the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).